# TSQL to get all rows from a recursive table

Tags: c#, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

This is a follow up of the question: [SQL Server to show a data tree in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314595/sql-server-to-show-a-data-tree-in-a-specific-format)

Now we have a second table that is related to the first one on the "leaf" rows:

table1:

```
   Itemid   Itemname    Itemfatherid
    itemA    theitemA    null
    itemB    theitemB    null
    itemC    theitemC    itemA
    itemD    theitemD    itemA
    itemE    theitemE    itemC
    itemF    theitemF    itemE
    itemG    theitemG    itemD
```

In this table itemF and itemG would be leafs (they dont have any children)

table2:

```
   Itemid   RelItemid
    item1    itemF
    item2    itemF
    item3    itemG
```

The visual relation would be like this:

```
-itemA
    -itemC
        -itemE
            itemF (item1, item2)
    -itemD
        itemG (item3)
itemB
```

And we need to get all the rows from the 2nd table that are related to the first table filtering it by an especified node.

Examples:

```
Filtering by node itemA: item1, item2, item3
Filtering by node itemE: item1, item2
Filtering by node itemD: item3
Filtering by node itemG: item3
Filtering by node itemB:
```

Sorry for the long post, its in order to cover any holes...thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we solved it looping throu the results and doing sqls to get related rows from the second table...not the desired solution but the one feasible

Answer (score 0):

i think that  [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://blog.iamkunalshah.com/2012/03/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions/)! may use full to you

Comment: In the related question we used CTEs the problem is that the resulting query is so complex already that we dont see how to combine it with this new condition